# Suppress XML documentation for specific properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I am using [project-built](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.90).aspx) XML documentation along with [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) to create automatically generated Web API documentation.

I want to keep some properties hidden from the documentation (to allow us to change their signature without notice) but I cannot figure out how to prevent these properties from being serialized into the XML in the first place.

How can I do this?